# This code can be rails unit test with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I'm studying rails and rspec.
And I made rspec unit test (request test) on rails application.
But after searching on google, I'm wonder if my job is on right way.
Can my code be a "Unit test by function(not a method, web site's feature ex)create, show, delete..) of rails application" ?

this is my code with request test.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Users', type: :request do
  let!(:users) { create_list(:user, 10) }
  let(:user_id) { users.first.id }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  def send_request_to_store_user(name, mailaddress)
    post '/users', params: {
      user: {
        name: users.first.name,
        mailaddress: users.first.mailaddress
      }
    }
  end

  def http_status_success_and_body_element_check(body_element)
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    expect(response.body).to include(body_element)
  end

  describe 'GET' do
    context 'Get /users test' do
      it 'test user list page' do
        get '/users'
        http_status_success_and_body_element_check('User List')
      end
    end

    context 'Get /users/create test' do
      it 'test user create page' do
        get '/users/create'
        http_status_success_and_body_element_check('create user')
      end
    end

    context 'Get /users/:id/edit' do
      it 'test user edit page' do
        get "/users/#{user_id}"
        http_status_success_and_body_element_check('edit user')
      end
    end

    context 'Get /users/:id' do
      it 'test user show page' do
        get "/users/#{user_id}"
        http_status_success_and_body_element_check('show user')
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'POST' do
    context 'test store new user' do
      it 'test create new user' do
        send_request_to_store_user(user.name, user.mailaddress)
        expect do
          create(:user)
        end.to change { User.count }.from(User.count).to(User.count + 1)
      end

      it 'test redirect after create' do
        send_request_to_store_user(user.name, user.mailaddress)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE' do
    it 'test delete user' do
      expect do
        delete "/users/#{user_id}"
      end.to change { User.count }.from(User.count).to(User.count - 1)
      expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
    end
  end

  describe 'PUT' do
    context 'user update' do
      it 'test user information update' do
        old_name = users.first.name
        new_name = 'new_name'
        expect do
          put "/users/#{user_id}", params: {
            user: {
              name: new_name
            }
          }
        end.to change { users.first.reload.name }.from(old_name).to(new_name)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

this is my code with test on model

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  it 'user must have name and mailaddress' do
    user = create(:user)
    expect(user).to be_valid
    expect(user.name).not_to be_nil
    expect(user.mailaddress).not_to be_nil
  end

  it 'mailaddress must include @' do
    # user = FactoryBot.create(:user)

    # If rails_helper.rb has config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods, 
    # Can use shortcut. Don't have to FactoryBot.create
    user = create(:user)
    # Test pass if email match with regexp
    expect(user.mailaddress).to match(/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/)
  end
end
```

Comment: In my opinion, testing Rails code is meaningless. Only test your own code and stub or mock anything that you didn't write. Trust that Rails is doing it's job as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these tests are valuable (meaningful).

Here's my reasoning:

What are these tests telling you? That the Rails router is working? That the controller is responding with the right action? Neither of these are your responsibility to test. Rails has that covered.

If you want to know "does the index page render?" and "can I CRUD a user?" then write system tests with Capybara that simulate the whole flow. That way you are testing the real-world interaction with your whole system.